# Finding a boolean submatrix isomorphic to a specific fixed set of other boolean matrices

Tags: algorithms, np-hard, matrices

Given a matrix $M$ of certain size $h\times w$, where $h\leq w$, for example $5\times 6$, are also given the following set $B$ of additional all-ones matrices, that I like to call target (b)oxes.

$$
\begin{matrix}
    Boxes: &
    \begin{bmatrix} % 2 x 5
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
    \end{bmatrix}
    &
    \begin{bmatrix} % 3 x 4
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1
    \end{bmatrix}
    &
    \begin{bmatrix} % 4 x 3
      1 & 1 & 1\\
      1 & 1 & 1\\
      1 & 1 & 1\\
      1 & 1 & 1
    \end{bmatrix}   
    &
    \begin{bmatrix} % 5 x 2
      1 & 1\\
      1 & 1\\
      1 & 1\\
      1 & 1\\
      1 & 1
    \end{bmatrix}\\
    Sizes: & 2 \times w - 1 & 3 \times w - 2 & 4\times w - 3 & 5\times w - 4
\end{matrix}
$$

As you can see, these specific boxes have sizes starting from $2\times w - 1$ up to $h\times w - h + 1$.

The problem is finding a submatrix of $M$ that is isomorphic with any of the boxes in $B$. In other words, swapping rows between them, and/or columns between them so that any of the boxes of $B$ can be placed, for example, in the top left corner of $M$.

If there is more than one solution, the box of maximal height must be choosen, and if there's more than one solution of maximal height, then the one with maximal height and width.

The problem has the following properties:

- $2 \leq h \leq w$.
- Each row of $M$ has at least one $0$.
- Deduced from the way $B$ is generated, for each $b\in B$ of size $b_h\times b_w$, it happens that $b_h + b_w - 1 = w$.

Is there a way of solving this problem in polynomial time? Can any technique from lineal algebra or numerical characterization of matrices help to the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is NP-hard; it is at least as hard as the biclique problem.

If you can solve the problem for a single shaped box, you can solve for all boxes by just iterating over all the boxes.  So your problem reduces to:

> Given a matrix $M$ and integers $h', w'$, find a $h'\times w'$ submatrix of $M$ that is all ones, or report that none exists.

This problem is NP-hard.  In particular, if we take any undirected bipartite graph $G$ with adjacency matrix $M$, then $M$ has an all-ones $k \times k$ submatrix if and only if $G$ has a $k$-biclique.  Testing for the presence of a $k$-biclique is NP-hard, so your problem must be, too.

Comment: I don't see 100% why both problems are equivalent, becase $M$ is not an adjacency matrix (it's not square or symmetrical).

Comment: Another thing... that I removed in a previous edition (damm myself, I will edit it after work), is that boxes has priorities, so the $5\times 2$ box has priority over $2\times 5$ because height has priority over width, so, could be there a way to take advantage of the knowledge that, if I'm trying an specific box is because we know the previous boxes have all failed?

Comment: @Peregring-lk, see edited answer; I should have stated that G is bipartite.  I proved it is NP-hard for a single box, so it follows that it is NP-hard in the general case, even if you take priority into account.

Comment: Why is it a biclique instead of a clique? My gut reaction would be to think that a k-clique (with self loops) looks precisely like a k x k submatrix of 1s under the permutation that leaves the k nodes of the clique at the beginning.

Comment: @BernardoSubercaseaux, because a submatrix can pick rows 1,2 and columns 3,4 (say), whereas a clique would require that if you picked rows 1,2 then you pick columns 1,2.

Comment: I have unmarked your answer as accepted because I'm not fully sure about how my problem connects to the biclique problem. The biclique problem is finding if a bipartite graph (and $M$ doesn't represent a graph because it's not even square), contains a complete bipartite graph $K_{i,i}$, and thus a bipartite graph whose disjoint sets have same size, but the target boxes are not necesarily square either. So none of the two conditions I gave match the biclique problem (unless my conditions are incorrect).

Comment: @Peregring-lk, the general case of your problem includes the special case of a square box; since the special case is NP-hard, the general case is, too.

Comment: @D.W Ok it's true that, when $M$ has an even width, one of the boxes would be square, provided that $h\geq \frac{w+1}{2}$, and $M$ can be square as well so you are right on that. I have to check for my specific case if all conditions can happen for some input: $M$ is square + has an even width + it's symmetrical.

Comment: @D.W. Last difference I see. When you swap rows and columns in an adjacency matrix, you are really relabelling vertices and so if you swap two rows you have to swap its matching columns to preserve the symmetry, however, in the problem I described I don't have this restriction. I can swap two rows and I'm done because I don't have any symmetry to preserve.

Comment: @Peregring-lk, not in a bipartite graph.

Comment: Not sure if the problems are equivalent, because I don't immediately see a reduction *from* this problem *to* biclique. But this problem is certainly at least as hard as biclique!

Comment: @j_random_hacker, good point.  Edited.